# interrupt a TCP-IP callback function in matlab

Tags: matlab, tcp

Recently wrote code that establishes a connection between two instances of matlab. I can send messages through the TCP-IP connection which will execute code. Now I'm trying to setup the code to be interruptible as I would like to start/stop a function through TCP-IP. Problem though is that sending a second command does nothing until the function is completed. Is there a way to interrupt a TCP-IP callback function?

code:

```
classdef connectcompstogether<handle
    properties
        serverIP
        clientIP
        tcpipServer
        tcpipClient
        Port = 4000;
        bsize = 8;

        earlystop
    end

    methods
        function gh = connectcompstogether(~)
            %           gh.serverIP = '127.0.0.1';
            gh.serverIP = 'localhost';
            gh.clientIP = '0.0.0.0';
        end

        function SetupServer(gh)
            gh.tcpipServer = tcpip(gh.clientIP,gh.Port,'NetworkRole','Server');
            set(gh.tcpipServer,'OutputBufferSize',gh.bsize);
            fopen(gh.tcpipServer);
            display('Established Connection')
        end

        function SetupClient(gh)
            gh.tcpipClient = tcpip(gh.serverIP,gh.Port,'NetworkRole','Client');
            set(gh.tcpipClient, 'InputBufferSize',gh.bsize);
            set(gh.tcpipClient, 'BytesAvailableFcnCount',8);
            set(gh.tcpipClient, 'BytesAvailableFcnMode','byte');
            set(gh.tcpipClient, 'BytesAvailableFcn', @(h,e)gh.recmessage(h,e));
            fopen(gh.tcpipClient);
            display('Established Connection')
        end
        function CloseClient(gh)
            fclose(gh.tcpipClient);
            gh.tcpipClient = [];
        end
    end
    methods
        function sendmessage(gh,message)
            fwrite(gh.tcpipServer,message,'double');
        end

        function recmessage(gh,h,e)
            Message = fread(gh.tcpipClient,gh.bsize/8,'double');

            if Message == 444
                gh.Funwithnumbers();
            elseif Message == 777
                gh.earlystop = 1;
            end
        end

        function Funwithnumbers(gh)
            x=1;
            while true
                if x > 5000, break;end
                if gh.earlystop == 1,break;end
                x = x+1;
                display(x)
            end

        end
    end
end
```

for ease to understand code.

server

```
Ser = connectcompstogether;
ser.SetupServer();
ser.sendmessage(333);
```

Client

```
cli = connectcompstogether;
cli.SetupClient();
```

Update:
So after going through the web, I have found out based on this [post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/332596-matlab-socket-is-not-interruptible) that the tcpip callback cannot be interrupt. The post was in 2017 which means my 2016a version definitely cannot interrupt a callback.

So An update to my question, Is it possible to start a subprocess in matlab to run the function. I just want to use the callback to start code. If I can start a subprocess from the callback. Than I should be able to free up the main process and use tcpip to start/stop a function on a different computer.

Update 2:
So I tried to utilize parallel processing using the 'spmd' command but the problem still persisted.

```
    function recmessage(gh,h,e)
        Message = fread(gh.tcpipClient,gh.bsize/8,'double');

        spmd
            switch labindex
                  case 1
                        if Message == 444
                             gh.Funwithnumbers();
                        elseif Message == 777
                             gh.earlystop = 1;
                       end
            end
       end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `timer` object, which is convenient to delay the execution of some function.

```
t=timer('ExecutionMode','singleShot', 'StartDelay',0, 'TimerFcn',@myCallback);
start(t);
```

In this case, the `StartDelay` is 0, so `myCallback` will be almost immediately added to the queue of tasks to be processed by Matlab. The execution however will start only after the callback to the `tcpip` object has been completed. It will block the queue once started, however.

You may try something like:

```
properties
    t=timer('ExecutionMode','singleShot', 'StartDelay',0, 'TimerFcn',@myCallback);
end

function tcpipCallback(gh,tcpObj,~)
message=fread(tcpObj,1,'double');
if message==444
   if strcmp(get(t,'Running'),'on')
     error('The function is running already');
   else
     set(gh.t,'UserData',false);
     start(gh.t);
   end
elseif message==777
   set(gh.t,'UserData',true);
end

function myCallback(tObj,~)
   ii=0;
   while ii<5000
     if get(tObj,'UserData'),break,end
     ii=ii+1;
     pause(.0001); %Pause to interrupt the callback; drawnnow might work too; or perhaps this is not needed at all.
   end
end
```